How Do I Change The Border Color And Text Color Of An Outline Button
I am trying to change the border color and also the text label color of an Outline button but I am getting errors. What is the best way to achieve this?
                   OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0))),
                      side: BorderSide(width: 5.0, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                    child: const Text("Crime"),
                  ),


Set the style of the button as:
style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),


Set the border color by specifying the side parameter in OutlinedButton.styleFrom.
Set the text color by specifying the foregroundColor in OutlinedButton.styleFrom.

In the above example, the red is the border color, and the blue is the text color.

